# Can I use Kendo MVC helpers inside templates?

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to use Kendo MVC helper Razor code in template as listed below:

```
<script id="some-reusable-control" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("details-window"))
</script>
```

But the problem is rendered HTML+JS contains a # (sharp symbol) that is rendered as part of #= # syntax inside template. So I getting 'parse error'.

```
<div id="details-window" style="display:none"></div><script>
 jQuery(function(){jQuery("#details-window
").kendoWindow({animation:false,modal:true,draggable:true /*, etc */ });});
</script>
```

Could anyone please provide me a solution of how to use Kendo helpers in templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use Kendo UI Widgets as content for a template you could use the ToClientTemplate method.
e.g.

```
<script id="some-reusable-control" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  @(Html.Kendo().Window()
      .Name("details-window")
      .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20596891/1204249 ? I'm having a similar problem.