# MVC helper inside a template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a kendo MVC helper inside a template (remote template file loaded like: http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/load-templates-external-files#remote-templates. I have a controller that sends to the client the generated markup)

My template file is something like:

```
<script id="my-pager-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    My pager

    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<Business.Data.MyPage>()
        .Name("myPagerListView")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("my-pager-item-template")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => 
            read.Action("GetMyPages","Page")
            )
        ).ToClientTemplate())

</script>

<script id="my-pager-item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template" >
    <div class="k-button" data-pager-item-pageid="${PageID}" data-pager-item-pagename="${Name}">
        <span>${ButtonText}</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

But the generated markup is giving me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in my browser console (chrome).

The markup generated by the helper is like this:

```
<div id="myPagerListView"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("\#myPagerListView").kendoListView({"dataSource":{"transport":{"prefix":"","read":{"url":"/Page/GetMyPages"}},"serverPaging":true,"serverSorting":true,"serverFiltering":true,"serverGrouping":true,"serverAggregates":true,"type":"aspnetmvc-ajax","filter":[],"schema":{"data":"Data","total":"Total","errors":"Errors","model":{"fields":{"PageID":{"type":"number"},"Name":{"type":"string"},"ButtonText":{"type":"string"}}}}},"template":kendo.template($('\#my-pager-item-template').html())});});
<\/script>

</script>
```

Can I use kendo helpers this way?
(In this post, it says that it can be used: [Can I use Kendo MVC helpers inside templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384097/1204249))

Answer (score 0):

I got that message a lot of times, your code is fine, the problem comes retrieving the data, kendo deserialize what it recieves from `read.Action("GetMyPages","Page")`, you probably are retrieving an HTML page instead of a json, so it tries to serialize something like `"<html ...."` and here you got the error, just check the url on chrome to check if you recive an json

i mean check http://yourdomain.com/Pages/GetPages/ (or the routing according to your app), you probably get an HTML page

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue also. I have come to realise (over the past 3 hours :( ) that this is because I was using ajax then the jquery html function to load the template file and that the error was happening with in jquery's function as it tried to parse than execute the template file which has been mangled for an unknown reason by kendo.
 (escaping that script tag and in my case inserting buttons in that space). 
Fortunatly when kendo Its self tries to use the template it does work. 
 
To get around this problem I rendered the partial view directly on the page.

Hope this helps.